# d3 Voronoi overlay min distance on Chrome? (Firefox works)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js

I am trying to add an Voronoi overlay on my chart, but it seems like when the interval between points are smaller than 20px, some path will never get selected, especially for the points in the start and of the end. Thanks to `musically_ut`, who notice that this is only happening on Chrome browser.

I went back to play with the original post on [Voronoi](http://bl.ocks.org/njvack/1405439), and found the same problem ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZbSaK/)).

```
  var vertices = d3.range(100).map(function(d, i) {        
    // return [Math.random() * w, Math.random() * h]; //original line
    return [i * 10, 10]; // change this line!
  });
```

I thought that this has something to do with the `r` value of the clipPath, but it was not the case: the problem still persist with a `r` value of `5`.

Comment: You need to rewrite your question completely, in a clear way. Otherwise, nobody would not understand anything.

Comment: Curiouser and curioser. This seems to happen only on Chrome. It works on Firefox and Safari.

Comment: @musically_ut, thank you for the formatting, good remark, it works for in Firefox! I am re-writing the question.

the irony: I was trying Voronoi overlay to better select on small instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went back to the documentation, and turns out that it recommended to add a clipPath when setting up the Voronoi function, which will solve the problem.

Instead of:

`d3.geom.voronoi(data)`

use

```
var padding = 0;
var vor = d3.geom.voronoi().clipExtent([[padding, padding], [w - padding, h - padding]])

  paths.selectAll("path")
    .data(vor(vertices))
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZbSaK/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I am posting my workaround on the problem, for anyone who faced a similar situation needing a quick fix. I am still looking for the reason on why this is happening.

My workaround was to create the overlay area manually, in this case the layout logic was fairly easy.

```
var col = 64;
var cr = 3;
var rwidth = (w / col);

var offset = (rwidth / 2);

// overlay: a rect that is placed around the circle space
svg.selectAll("blank")
    .data(d3.range(nbr))
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr({
        "x": function(d,i){ return (i % col) * (rwidth) - offset; },
        "y": function(d,i){ return (Math.floor(i / col) + 1) * (rwidth) - offset; },
        "width": rwidth,
        "height": rwidth,
        "fill": "white"
    })
    .on("mousemove", function(d, i){
        // do what you want to do when overlay is triggered
        d3.selectAll(".glss" + i)
            .transition()
    })

// the actual circle
svg.selectAll("blank")
    .data(d3.range(nbr))
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr({
        "cx": function(d,i){ return (i % col) * (w / col)},
        "cy": function(d,i){ return (Math.floor(i / col) + 1) * (w / col); },
        "r": cr,
        "fill": function(d,i){ return "#7E07A9"; },
        "class": function(d,i){ return "glss glss" + i; }
    })
```